# Looking forward some kind of bi-dimensional array output format

Tags: c, arrays

So, i'm doing a program using bidimensional arrays and i'm actually using a function to print my arrays, it's not bad but i'd like another way to print them.

| 1  0 11 -2 |

| 3  7 -1 -7 |

| 0 -8  5  4 |

http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/9330/cln8.png

The problem can't really think of a way to make a for cycle that print them like  that.
as the just the first and last column has the char.

Please if you find a way to, use cin/cout as we've just been introduced to them.

PS. We've using C coding but with cin/cout, so no pointers ecc

Thank you for your time.

Comment: look at output formatting for cout http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/iomanip.html

Comment: maybe you can figure out how long the value you're going to print is going to be so that you can pad it appropriately

Comment: sometimes quick solution can be to use `"\t"` instead of `" "` (space)

Comment: cin/cout are c++, not c. Please fix the tag!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some idea of how wide each column should be.
Then you can do something like

```
cout << setw(3) << value;
```

to output the values from the table.